# Mysql order function

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a problem with a grouping function.
My `mysql` table is:

```
Product    Color       Sellout
Test1       white       80%
Test2       Red         70%
Test1       Red         90%
Test3       Black       50%
```

I need that ordered by sellout but grouped by products name and color.
Like:

```
Test1     Red       90%
Test1     White     80%
Test2     Red       70%
Test3     Black     50%
```

Please help me, I think it's simple but i'm going crazy!

Comment: Can you share the details of that sorting rules? What do you mean by "ordered by sellout but grouped by products name and color"?

Answer (score 1):

Sellout does not exist in  the GROUP-BY  clause. So, it should be used by aggregation functions. The MIN() is one of them and is quite light operation.

See below.

```
SELECT Product, Color, MIN(Sellout) AS _SELLOUT_
FROM MY_MYSQL_TABLE
GROUP BY Product, Color
ORDER BY _SELLOUT_ DESC
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your query - what's the need to use `MIN`?

Comment: Okay. I added some explanation.

Comment: And why **exactly** did you use `MIN` and not `MAX`?

Comment: group by will leave only 1 row of that group

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is multiple ordering. Try something like these:

```
ORDER BY Sellout DESC, Product, Color
```

or

```
ORDER BY Product, Color, Sellout DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your table structure, I'd say, what you call grouped by is just another order by, like

```
SELECT Product, Color, Sellout
FROM Table
ORDER BY Product, Sellout DESC
```

Result:

```
Test1     Red       90%
Test1     White     80%
Test2     Red       70%
Test3     Black     50%
```

With `GROUP BY` you "fold" lines with the same values from the group-by column and apply an aggregation function (like `SUM`) for all the other (selected) columns.

A group by query and result look like this:

```
SELECT Product, AVG(Sellout)
FROM Table
```

Result:

```
Test1     85
Test2     70
Test3     50
```

Answer (score 0):

If i apply this queries it's ok only when data it's not like this :

Product    Color       Sellout
Test1       white       80%
Test2       Red         70%
Test1       Red         90%
Test3       Black       50%
Test3       Red         99%

Result has to be

Product    Color       Sellout
Test3       Red         99%
Test3       Black       50%
Test1       Red         90%
Test1       white       80%
Test2       Red         70%